# Why does C# is keyword return true for double, but false for float even though casting to float works?

Tags: c#, casting, floating-point

**Motivation:**  I have a method that returns a dynamic datatype.  The value is coming from a database and I know that the value will either be a float, double, or string.  I don't want to use the value if it is a string, so I wrote the following code:

```
if (value is float)
{
    myVariable = (float)value;
}
```

My expectation was that this code would execute whether the actual type of value was double or float because of the following snippet from the documentation of the 'is' keyword:

> An **is** expression evaluates to true if the provided expression is non-null,and the provided object can be cast to the provided type without causing an exception to be thrown.

Found here: [is (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx)

However, when the type is double, (value is float) returns false and the assignment does not execute.  But, I changed my code to this:

```
if (value is double)
{
    myVariable = (float)value;
}
```

and it works fine when the type of value is double - even though according to the documentation I shouldn't be able to cast to a float because (value is float) returns false.

**My Question:** Why does (value is float) return false in the case where value is a double (which can be cast to a float without exception)?

**EDIT - Short program demonstrating**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic d = 1.0;
        Console.WriteLine(d is double);
        Console.WriteLine(d is float);
        float f = (float)d;
        Console.WriteLine(f);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. If the compile-time type of `value` is actually `dynamic`, then that makes a significant difference. The MSDN description of `is` isn't as clear as the C# language specification is on this matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, this is because the type is `dynamic`. That basically means the meaning of the `float` cast depends on the *execution-time* type of the value.

The `is` operator is checking whether `float` and `double` are the same type - and they're not, which is why it's returning false.

However, there *is* an explicit conversion from `double` to `float`, which is why the cast is working. I wouldn't use that MSDN C# reference to work out the finer details of how the language behaves - the language specification is normally a better bet.

Comment: the languge spec is a pretty intimidating document for me.  Can you recommend what sections would most clarify this issue for me, i.e. should I start with the section on casting, dynamic types, or the is operator?

Comment: @Gaber-ber: The section on the `is` operator (7.10.10) is probably the best starting point here... then think that as a rule of thumb, the `dynamic` type is handled by working out what the compiler *would* have done based on the execution-time type of the value, not the compile-time type.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I guess it is because there is no implicit conversion. See [Implicit Numeric Conversions Table (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly casting double value to float variable. It is perfectly fine.
When you checking the type, it is exact type match.
What you need is:

```
if (value is double || value is float)
{
    myVariable = (float)value;
}
```